# I want to show leave duration in float value

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I created the field **half_day_allowed** in *hr_leave_rules.py*

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

class HRLeaveRules(models.Model):
    _name = 'hr_leave_rules.leave_rules'

    half_day_allowed = fields.Selection([
        ('yes',"Yes"),
        ('no',"No")],
        string="Half Day Allowed", required=True)
```

and also,I have inherited the fields **get_number_of_days** which calculates  leave applied is for how many days and **holiday_status_id** which indicates leave type . what I am trying to do is if for particular **holiday_status_id** if **half_day_allowed** is 'yes' then in **get_number_of_days** it should take *float* values otherwise it will take *integer* value. For this I tried the below code but it is not working.plz help me out.

*leave_type.py*

```
from odoo import fields, models, api, _
from math import ceil
from datetime import timedelta
from openerp.exceptions import UserError

HOURS_PER_DAY = 8

class leave(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.holidays"


    @api.onchange('number_of_days_temp')
    def _holiday_status_id(self):

        current = self.env['hr_leave_rules.leave_rules'].search([(
                'holiday_status_id','=',self.holiday_status_id.id)])

    @api.onchange('date_from')
    def _onchange_date_from(self):

        date_from = self.date_from
        date_to = self.date_to

        if date_from and not date_to:
            date_to_with_delta = fields.Datetime.from_string(date_from) + timedelta(hours=HOURS_PER_DAY)
            self.date_to = str(date_to_with_delta)
            current = self.env['hr_leave_rules.leave_rules'].search([(
                    'holiday_status_id','=',self.holiday_status_id.id)])

            if current.half_day_allowed == 'yes':
                if (date_to and date_from) and (date_from <= date_to):
                    self.number_of_days_temp = self._get_number_of_days(
                            date_from, date_to, self.employee_id.id)
                else:
                    self.number_of_days_temp = 0
            else:
                if (date_to and date_from) and (date_from <= date_to):
                        self.number_of_days_temp = ceil(self._get_number_of_days(
                            date_from, date_to, self.employee_id.id))
                else:
                    self.number_of_days_temp = 0

    @api.onchange('date_to')
    def _onchange_date_to(self):

        date_from = self.date_from
        date_to = self.date_to

        current = self.env['hr_leave_rules.leave_rules'].search([(
                'holiday_status_id','=',self.holiday_status_id.id)])

        if current.half_day_allowed == 'yes':
            if (date_to and date_from) and (date_from <= date_to):
                self.number_of_days_temp = self._get_number_of_days(
                    date_from, date_to, self.employee_id.id)
            else:
                self.number_of_days_temp = 0
        else:
            if (date_to and date_from) and (date_from <= date_to):
                self.number_of_days_temp = ceil(self._get_number_of_days(
                    date_from, date_to, self.employee_id.id))
            else:
                self.number_of_days_temp = 0
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem? From your code I am not sure **what is not working**.

Comment: @sg.sysel I have edited my question. kindly go through it once again.

Comment: So what is the error you're getting? (e.g. not getting half-days but only full days even if `current.half_day_allowed == 'yes'`)

Comment: @sg.sysel yes, its not showing correct get_number_of_days in both the cases i.e., in 'yes' and 'no'

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin...

Firstly, if you have a field that is Yes/No, it should be defined as a `Boolean` field, not as a `Char` field. [Fields Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#field-incremental-definition). It will allow you to do simpler `if`/`else` logic, not to mention it's just a better practice.

```
if half_day_allowed:
    # Do this way
else:
    # Do that way
```

Secondly, if you have repetitive code, you should break it into its own method for readability. [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

You've repeated this entire section twice:

```
if half_day_allowed == 'yes':
    if (date_to and date_from) and (date_from <= date_to):
        self.number_of_days_temp = self._get_number_of_days(
                date_from, date_to, self.employee_id.id)
    else:
        self.number_of_days_temp = 0
else:
    if (date_to and date_from) and (date_from <= date_to):
            self.number_of_days_temp = ceil(self._get_number_of_days(
                date_from, date_to, self.employee_id.id))
    else:
        self.number_of_days_temp = 0
```

Instead, just create a new method and call it when you need it.

```
@api.multi
def get_number_of_days_temp(self, half_day_allowed=False):
    self.ensure_one()
    if half_day_allowed == 'yes':
        # Do this
    else:
        # Do that

@api.onchange('date_from')
def _onchange_date_from(self):
    ...
    self.number_of_days_temp = self.get_number_of_days_temp(current.half_day_allowed)

@api.onchange('date_to')
def _onchange_date_to(self):
    ...
    self.number_of_days_temp = self.get_number_of_days_temp(current.half_day_allowed)
```

Finally, to determine what the problem is with not getting the expected results, we need more information from you. All you've said so far is:

> I tried the below code but it is not working.
>
> Its not showing correct get_number_of_days in both the cases i.e., in 'yes' and 'no'

This is not helpful to determine the problem. Is there an error message? Is it returning invalid data? If so, what are the inputs and outputs and what are expecting it should be?

Without knowing anything further, the only guess I can make is that your `number_of_days_temp` field (which you haven't included the field definition in your question) is defined as an `Integer` field, in which case it will always ignore the decimals. It must be defined as a `Float` for this to work.